# Is For loop in reverse better?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Is there any difference in time space complexity for these two?

```
for (int i=0; i<= 100; i++) {
    System.out.println("hi");
}

for (int i=100; i>= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("hi");
}
```

And what if the loop is larger and complex? Like when `i <= 1000000`

Comment: Both are O(N) so the same complexity!

Comment: @RossC untill you put a break somewhere inside the loop

Comment: @BigMike not sure I understand you there. The time complexity is the same, how does a break affect the loop/complexity? Genuine question, never considered that!

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran your answer below is `Too bored` :)

Comment: I was thinking about inefficient search on ordered collections, while iterating the datas, if they're somehow sorted, going in forward or reverse order may shorten the number of iterations, but yuo need to break inside the loop body.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference in space or time complexity between the two.

I'd be curious to hear why you thought there might be.

P.S. Of course, if the actual code is different, then the answer might be different too.

Comment: I'd say, first one is better because of clarity.

Comment: @hsz: The question is not about "better", it is about space complexity.

Comment: Not even if it is larger and complex loop?

Answer (score 0):

For these simple loops? No. You're just working with a constant string, some of `System.out.println()`'s overhead, and an iterated primitive.

However, for more complex nested loops, there could be differences, especially if loops are nested with changing inner loop lengths.

Answer (score 0):

No both has same time space complexity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @wudzik what is the answer for this question then? take a look at other answers too.

Answer (score 0):

As such no difference in time complexity i.e O(N).

Deciding on which approach to follow is your design specific. For example if I have to find largest prime factor of a given number I would probably use 2nd approach. So basically it is design(of your intended project) specific.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't break out of the loop with some logic (depending on index variable) there should be no difference in space/complexity.

If you need to iterate on every single value of your index, going in reverse order is exactly like going in forward.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example is not. For larger arrays it might be slower on some systems.

Usually systems are optimized for accessing memory sequentially. As long as memory access pattern is predictable both loops have same efficiency but on older machines or different architectures things may be different.

For space complexity is not (i miss-read the question)

Comment: Why in older machines? Let it be a complex and large loop

Comment: Based on your access pattern the memory controller tries to predict what memory page your code will need next and loads that into the L1, L2, and L3 caches such that by the time code finished executing current iteration it has data prepared for the next. If access pattern is not predictable you will get a lot of cache misses and application will be slower. This is a different topic, sorry for mentioning it in this context.